# Serilog sub-logger configuration

Tags: serilog

I found this configuration using a silent sub-logger and I can't think of a reason for it. I wonder if it is for some kind of fallback.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .WriteTo.Logger(Serilog.Core.Logger.None)
    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Unless the fluent construction chain won't let you create the logger until you do a .WriteTo, I reckon it's a Null Object without a purpose/reason